# How to stack two bottom sheets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to stack two bottom sheets each other in flutter as show in photo. The upper one is shown when in error state. In photo, it builds with alert dialog. I want is with bottom sheet. How can I get it?
[image]

**Edit:**
Here is my code that I want to do. Lower bottom sheet is with pin field, `autoComplete`. `autoComplete` trigger StreamController, and then `streamBuilder` watch **Error** state and show dialog.

```
confirmPasswordModalBottomSheet(
      BiometricAuthRegisterBloc biometricAuthRegBloc) {
    showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: biometricAuthRegBloc.biometricAuthRegisterStream,
            builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<ResponseObject>biometricAuthRegSnapShot) {
              if (biometricAuthRegSnapShot.hasData) {
                if (biometricAuthRegSnapShot.data!.messageState ==
                    MessageState.requestError) {
                  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: 
                (BuildContext context){
                    return Container(
                     width: 200,height: 200,
                     child: Center(child: Text('Helllllllllo'),),);
                  });
                }
              }
              return SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 300,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: margin30,
                    ),
                    Text(CURRENT_PIN_TITLE),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: margin30,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: margin60, right: margin60),
                      child: PinCodeField(
                        pinLength: 6,
                        onChange: () {},
                        onComplete: (value) {
                          biometricAuthRegBloc.biometricAuthRegister(
                              biometricType:_biometricAuthTypeForApi,
                              password: value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: margin30,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
                    margin80),
                      child: AppButton(
                        onClick: () {},
                        label: CANCEL_BTN_LABEL,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, 
                      horizontal: 30),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        FINGER_PRINT_DIALOG,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
```

When I do like that above, I get  `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` Error and why? Sorry for my previous incomplete question.

Comment: Simple! you can init bottom sheet on dialog of error state

Comment: What the issue there?

Comment: Issue is I can't stack two bottom sheet each other.Example: press submit on first bottom sheet, if error come second bottom sheet appear and press **OK** on second bottom sheet, only second sheet will ```pop```.

Comment: on OK click are you want to pop both bottom sheet?

Comment: No, only want to ```pop``` upper bottom sheet and lower bottom sheet will remain to fill correct  pin again.

Comment: create a custom bottom sheet class and use `Navigator.push`

Comment: So on OK click you have to use Navigator.pop(ctx);

Comment: No.. my issue is not ```pop```. I can't stack each bottom sheet. When stack each other I always get ``` setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.``` error.

Comment: Not getting clear view of your quetions

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused with your question but stacking two bottomsheet is just easy. You just need to call the showModalBottomSheet whenever you want it shown to user. You can check out the following implementation:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet 1'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Show second modal 2'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 200,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet 2'),
                                      ElevatedButton(
                                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text('Show bottom sheet 1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Stacked bottom sheet]

Answer (score -1):

I have solution. All I need to do is, need to add `WidgetBinding.insatance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp){showModalBottomSheet()});` in the StreamBuilder `return`.